# Reading help, ideal of an ideal is an ideal?

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals, proof-explanation

While in general it is not true that an ideal of an ideal is an ideal, this proof in Humphreys confuses me. Could someone please explain to me why the underlined sentences are true?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take an element $i$ in an ideal $I$ of $L_1.$ Notice that for any $l\in L_1, m \in L_1^\perp,$ $[l, m]=0$ (this is true for any two ideals with trivial intersection).
Now, writing $l\in L = l_1 + m,$ we see that $[i, l] = [i, l_1] + [i, m] = [i, l_1] \in I.$

Comment: Therefore an ideal of an ideal is an ideal for semisimple Lie algebras, correct?

Comment: Apparently that's what the argument shows (I am not completely comfortable about saying this in infinite dimensions).

Comment: Yes, this book assumes finite dimensional.