# If $L$ is semisimple, how is this ideal of $L$ semisimple?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, lie-algebras, solution-verification

From Humphrey's book, page 23:

> [image]

---

In the second paragraph, it is stated that any ideal of $L_1$ is an ideal of $L$. **How is this so?**

Also, it is stated that this implies $L_1$ is semisimple. **How is this so?**

Answer (score 1):

The first question has already been [answered before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629723/reading-help-ideal-of-an-ideal-is-an-ideal).

Concerning the other question, let $\mathfrak a$ be a solvable ideal of $L_1$. Then it is a solvable ideal of $L$. But $L$ is semisimple, which means that its only solvable ideal is $\{0\}$. So, $\mathfrak a=\{0\}$, which proves that $L_1$ is semisimple.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.